# Configuring Jetty with SSL/TLS and Keystore

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, kotlin, keystore

I have created key and certificate, signed by root CA using OpenSSL. I'm trying to use server.key file as keystore and performing it in code:

```
private fun setupHttps(server : Server, port: Int) {
val https = HttpConfiguration()
https.addCustomizer(SecureRequestCustomizer())

val sslFactory = SslContextFactory()
sslFactory.keyStorePath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "..", "server.key").toString()
sslFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password")

val sslConnector = ServerConnector(
    server,
    SslConnectionFactory(sslFactory, "http/1.1"),
    HttpConnectionFactory(https)
)

sslConnector.port = port
server.connectors = arrayOf(sslConnector)
```

}

But I had this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no valid keystore
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:998)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at ru.servicesmarket.server.LaunchKt.main(launch.kt:44)
```

Comment: *`IllegalStateException: no valid keystore`* seems to indicate you don't have a well configured Keystore. It does not appear to be related to your SSL/TLS configuration.

Comment: Try a simple `myKeystorePath.exists()` check on the path you think you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is a problem with your path / location of the keystore. 
This exception is thrown when the keystore is not found, which is kind of confusing.

Comment: I had the same with Java Spark Framework which runs on Jetty. your answer was very helpful, path was the issue. giving absolute path helped.